# Can I measure a reaction time of answer to the dialog box made with Dlg in Spyder (Python 3.8)?

Tags: python, time, spyder, measure, psychopy

I'm making an experiment in which subjects must solve an anagram and write the answer in dialog box made with Dlg (psychopy.gui).

So, it looks like this:

```
answer=psychopy.gui.Dlg(title="Answer")

answer.addField()    
     answer.show()
```

So, my question is: can I somehow measure a reaction time (it starts when a dialog box opens and stops with the response)?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the clock/timer class ([see here](https://psychopy.org/api/clock.html)).

"A convenient class to keep track of time in your experiments. You can have as many independent clocks as you like"

Comment: Thank you, but I am already using the clock for something in my experiment and I don't know how to use it in this context. I need my timer to start when the dialog box shows, and to stop when the subject responds. Where do I put my timer in this situation (sorry, I'm new in programing): answer=psychopy.gui.Dlg(title="Answer")        
                                        answer.addField()                                                  
                                        answer.show().